# How to find \mathstrut belongs to which package in ctan.org?

Tags: ctan, strut

I like to read about `\mathstrut` in ctan.org. I went there in **ctan.org** and hit browser then packages but I could not find anything about `\mathstrut`. Would you help me where to find `\mathstrut` in **ctan.org**?

Comment: The `\mathstrut` macro is defined in plain TeX and all other typical TeX formats (e.g. LaTeX) borrow the same definition of this macro from plain TeX. The macro is documented in TeXbook pp. 131 and 360.

Answer (score 7):

If you do from a terminal

```
latexdef -s mathstrut
```

(the backslash in front of the command is optional) you get

```
% latex.ltx, line 5869:
\DeclareRobustCommand\mathstrut{\vphantom(}
```

The recommended syntax would actually be `\vphantom{(}`, but many parts of the LaTeX kernel have code that's stripped down to a bare minimum in order to save memory which was very scarce when LaTeX2e was released.

This means that `\mathstrut`

1. is defined in the LaTeX kernel;
2. is an ordinary symbol, as far as spacing is concerned;
3. it takes no horizontal space;
4. it takes as much vertical space as a parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks. What does terminal mean when we say we do from a terminal?

Comment: @Aria A command prompt such as bah or powershell, depending on your operating system.

Answer (score 5):

`\mathstrut` is a basic command and does not belong to any particular package. Here's a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}
$\sqrt2 + \sqrt\alpha = \sqrt{\mathstrut 2} + \sqrt{\mathstrut\alpha}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @dwolfeu, do you know where in ctan.orge they talk about \mathstrut?

Comment: @Aria You're welcome. CTAN is a repository of TeX packages, not website for general TeX advice and tips. Try [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/mathstrut.htm) or [_A Primer of Mathematical Writing_](https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-112/) by Krantz.

Comment: Thanks. What does MWE mean?

Comment: MWE stands for [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1).